# How do I use the Red cURL binding?

Tags: curl, red

I am just getting started with Red and I need help to get the cURL binding working.

The cURL link from the main red-lang site takes you here

http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-cURL/dir?ci=tip

But there is only a small example using Red/System hence I am not sure how to load the binding in Red directly.

I need to get this working on Mac, Linux and maybe Windows so I would appreciate any pointers to differences between these platforms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things to address:

1. Next, there are some dependencies between bindings.  I am maintaining a [github clone](https://github.com/kealist/RS-fossil-mirror) if you don't want to use the script `download.r` in the [Red-test](http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-test/dir?ci=tip) files with Fossil.  The cURL library explicitly depends on the C-library binding.  I didn't look, but like depends on the Common binding at a lower level.
2. Because of the lack of `url!` type in Red at the moment, you pass the function `read-url` a `string!` or a `c-string!` more specifically.
3. With Red/System bindings used in Red, the ideal situation is to have a wrapper that abstracts the lower level code.  You can see this on TryRebol with running `read "http://www.google.com"`.  Although this console build does not seem to use cURL binding for that implementation.
4. In order to use a Red/System binding in Red, you need to use the `#system-global` directive.  Here is a simple script that grabs the data from a website:

   ```
   Red[]

   #system-global [
       #include %../cURL.reds
       with curl [
           print read-url "http://www.red-lang.org"
       ]
   ]
   ```

Comment: This works well. I used the github repository from step 1 above as ANSI.reds is required. I also need to install libcurl by running `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` on linux. The other trick was to use `red -c` as I forgot that the interpreter will not run Red/System code directly.