# performing Network I/O in Red using bindings

Tags: rebol, red

I read that there were bindings to perform GET and POST in the Red programming language. Could someone kindly show me a simple example that does something like "wget http://www.google.com"?

Comment: Red will ultimately be aiming to do things like Rebol does, e.g. **`read http://hostilefork.com`** and such.  The interim state until the port model is implemented will require use of a binding to something like cURL, [and there is one](http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-cURL/artifact/c8403b9beb94ee6e) if you want to chase that down.  *(My personal suggestion is generally to learn Rebol and trust the goal of Red is to be no lesser, so a library binding is a poor substitute.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cURL binding for Red which is described in more detail in this question.

[How do I use the Red cURL binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724042/how-do-i-use-the-red-curl-binding)

It will not give you the nice `print read http://red-lang.org` syntax, but I understand that adding this protocol to Red is on the road mapfor the future.